# не работает php код

Tags: php, html, post

Всем привет, делаю простенький проект без фреймворков и всего такого. Написал код обычной формы для заполнения данных, и создал php страницу на которую эти данные будут отправляться, но при переходе на эту страницу мне просто показывается код в текстовом виде

код формы

```
<!-- форма для отправки данных на почту-->
        <form action="send.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="client-name" placeholder="Укажите имя" required>
            <input type="text" name="client-number" placeholder="Укажите номер" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>
```

код php файла

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['client-name'];
$number = $_POST['client-number'];


echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $number;
```

прикрепляю еще скриншот того что будет если перейти к файлу send.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы закрыли код php в конце **?>** <?php echo $_POST['client-name']; echo '<br>'; echo $_POST['client-number']; ?>

Comment: Да, закрывал, он вот тот же текст и пишет, то есть весь код он просто пишет текстом

Comment: Вероятно, у Вас не включен PHP в Вашем сервере. Создайте PHP-файл с содержимым `<?php phpinfo() ?>` и если Вы не видите информацию о текущей конфигурации PHP, значит PHP не включен.

Comment: у меня проект не на сервере, я просто создал в phpstorm проект и там сделал index страницу и файл send.php то есть проект даже не на локалке а просто на компе

Comment: Поверьте - когда будет ошибка синтаксиса вы это поймете!) В данном случае это ошибка не кода, а отсутствия сервера, который должен обрабатывать этот самый php код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы работал php - нужен обработчик. Поэтому Вам нужно либо установить php (https://ospanel.io/ или https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/index.html проще всего, устанавливается сразу php, mysql, Apache и тд ) на компьютер, либо запускаться на сервере.

Браузер не будет обрабатывать php. А сейчас это просто выводится как текст.